# Reading shared resource efficiently

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading

I have multiple threads, any of these threads can write to a string that is accessed by any of the other threads.

I cannot write and read at the same time, but I don't see any reason why I cannot read the same resource twice from two different threads.

How would I allow asynchronous reading on a string, without allowing asynchronous writing and reading at the same time, in C++?

I'd envisioned that I'd somehow wait for ownership of a Mutex and somehow let other read operations know that the owning thread is performing a read operation and not write operation, so it can read as well, but I can't really put a simple flag saying "I'm reading" somewhere because as soon as the second read ignores the Mutex because of the flag, the first read operation would exit and a write operation could occur whilst the second read operation is being performed.

I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: My guess is that you want atomic updates. One way to achieve that is to have threads access the data through a pointer, and have updates make the pointer point to a different location. That way, readers would never see an piece of data in an inconsistent state (ie, half updated).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is known as [**The Readers-Writers Problem**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readers%E2%80%93writers_problem).

I suppose once you know that, it should be easy to identify solutions. In fact, the linked article presents a few of them.

```
semaphore wrt=1, mutex=1;
readcount=0;

writer()
{
    wait(wrt);
    // Writing is done
    signal(wrt);
}

reader()
{
    wait(mutex);
        readcount++;
        if (readcount == 1)
            wait(wrt);
    signal(mutex);
    // Do the Reading
    // (Critical Section Area)
    wait(mutex);
        readcount--;
        if (readcount == 0)
            signal(wrt);
    signal(mutex);
}
```

<sub>Copied one of the solutions to prevent (unlikely) link rot</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at `boost::shared_mutex`.

> The class boost::shared_mutex provides an implementation of a multiple-reader / single-writer mutex.

Comment: I'm really not a fan of boost, for me it often has one use to make one problem slightly easier - which does not warrant the size of the library.

Answer (score 1):

The Win32 API supplies a "Slim Reader/Writer Lock" for this situation.  They are set up and used similar to Critial Sections.  First InitializeSRWLock is used to create the lock object.  After this, a reader-only thread calls AcquireSRWLockShared before accessing the shared resource.  A thread which might modify the resource would use AcquireSRWLockExclusive instead.  When finished accessing the shared resource, locks are released with either ReleaseSRWLockShared or ReleaseSRWLockExclusive.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa904937(v=vs.85).aspx